# Object List to Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a list of type object as follows,

`List<object>` recordList

which will contain database record(integer,string) as follows,

```
[[1,AAAAAAAA],[2,BBBBBB]]
```

I need to split the data in the list and put into 
`Hashmap<Integer,String>` as follows,

I do knw how to split the data form the object list and poplualte the hashmap.
How to populate the Hashmap with the data from list?

Comment: `1,AAAAAAAA` a single attribute or two different ?

Comment: Is each entry in the list of type String?

Comment: I found same question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100486/java-create-a-list-of-hashmaps

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<Integer,String> m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
Iterator<String> ite = l.iterator();
while(ite.hasNext())
{
    String sTemp[] =ite.next().split(",");
    m.put(Integer.parseInt(sTemp[0]), sTemp[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

   for (MyObject element : list) {
       if (element != null)
           map.put(element.getInt(), element.getString());
   }
```

Comment: You could explain your answer a bit, at least tell the assumptions you made (since question is rather vague).

Answer (score 0):

if your `List<object>` contains`Object[]`, you can do it like

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map  = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for( Object obj : recordList) {
   Object[] objA = (String[]) obj ;
   map.put((Integer) objA[0],(String) objA[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package listHashMap;
import java.util.*;
public class MyList {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        List<String> aList=new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<Integer,String> aMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        aList.add("AAAA");
        aList.add("BBBB");
        for(int i=0;i<aList.size();i++){
            aMap.put(i+1,aList.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println(aMap.toString());

    }

}
```