# Java Complex Collection

Tags: java, collections

I have data in this format: (in a file)

```
key1:fieldname1:fieldvalue1
key1:fieldname2:fieldvalue2
key2:fieldname1:fieldvalue1
```

I need this to be formatted to:

```
{key1=[{fieldname1=fieldvalue1,fieldname2=fieldvalue2}],key2=[{fieldname1=fieldvalue1}]}
```

As you can see it involves Map and ArrayList.
I actually need it in Map and ArrayList.

Please suggest.
Thank you

Comment: Do you need text format or format to Map and ArrayList actually?

Comment: @libik Thanks for your reply. I actually need to format to Map and ArrayList

Comment: Can't say much without more info but, first problem would be that an arraylist can contain one object (NO PRIMITIVES) per entry. your entry seems to have 2 values / objects depending on the datatype. So create a wrapper class containing fields 1 and 2, and add those to an arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Find string method "split" and how to use it and also how to read text file line by line. By this, you can easily parse line by line and get what key, fieldname and fieldvalue is.

Then you can go as following for each line:

1. If key does not exist in your map, create empty array in it.
2. Add item to array specified at given key

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String[] str = {"key1:fieldname1:fieldvalue1", "key1:fieldname2:fieldvalue2", "key2:fieldname1:fieldvalue1"};
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    for (String s: str) {
        String[] temp = s.split(":");

        if (map.get(temp[0]) == null) {
            map.put(temp[0], new ArrayList());
        }
        map.get(temp[0]).add(temp[1] + "=" + temp[2]);
    }
```

This example is under the assumption that `fieldname1:fieldvalue2` need to be stored as string. You can get the high level idea and then modify according to your requirements

Comment: Thank you. temp[1] + "=" + temp[2]   . This is a string, but my arraylists should have maps

Comment: @sash Like I said in answer, you get the high level view of what needs to be done. You can tweak the answer according to your requirements. :) Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100486/java-create-a-list-of-hashmaps) to add `maps` into `list`